# Slow connection to Internet only on my Macbook

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, macbook-pro

Hi I'm experimenting something weird related with my connection to Internet.

Scenario 1: In my house with my roomates.

I live in small apartment with other 2 persons and we work together. When we have some Zoom or Hangouts meetings I'm the only one with unstable connection and frequently I was kick off from the call.

Scenario 2: Right now I'm with my parents (you know for Xmas and New year).

Here with my parents also I have slow connection, I was realized a test with speedtest and I get: 2.13Mbps Download and 16.47Mbps Upload. When I realized the same test from my iPhone connected to the same network I get: 42.4Mbps Download and 20.4Mbps Upload

I'm very confused why always I get slow connections on this Macbook. What do you think it could be?

Comment: Which model/generation of Macbook? What type of wireless network?

Comment: have you consider trying a different router/modem, another user solved the slow network problem by this method.  https://superuser.com/questions/215085/internet-very-slow-on-one-computer-but-not-another